# sql query with array of intervals

Tags: mysql

how to make sql query to find all unique users from table user_login which logged in
in between   day 1 and  (day 1  - minus 10 days )
day 2 and  (day 2 - minus 10 days )
day 3  and  (day 3  - minus 10 days )
....
day n and (day n  - minus 10 days )

the smartest thing i tried is case but my array of days is too huge to use that

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM user_login
WHERE login_date BETWEEN 'day 1' AND ('day 1' - INTERVAL 10 DAY)

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM user_login
WHERE login_date BETWEEN 'day 2' AND ('day 2' - INTERVAL 10 DAY)

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM user_login
WHERE login_date BETWEEN 'day 3' AND ('day 3' - INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Comment: Update your post with sample input tables and expected output. That will help us understand more about your problem.

Comment: Is your list of days available in a table, or could it be loaded in a CTE?

Comment: When you use `BETWEEN`, the first argument has to be lower (earlier in time than) the second. So it needs to be `BETWEEN ('day 1' - INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND 'day 1'`

Comment: You can use a stored procedure to create all the `UNION` subqueries dynamically with `PREPARE`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.